# How do I unscrew the backdoor of a Dell laptop

Tags: screwdriver

I have been trying to unscrew the backdoor of Inspiron 15R 5521 (purchased in 2013) with

1. Phillips #1 Screwdriver
2. Sunglasses screwdriver

I unscrew Counter-clockwise but the screws just move.

My concern is I may have ruined the threads of the screw (I struggled and got frustrated after few hours!)

Is this a gone case? Or should I spend few dollars on Amazon, Phillips # 0. But what is guarantee back-door will unscrew.

I want to make sure I can unscrew (see pink arrows) BEFORE I purchase a $60-something hard-drive to replace the old one.

Please help!!!

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't a home improvement question per [the definition on this site](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just searched and it said unlock and remove battery, loosen the 2 screws securing the service cover on the bottom. Now you can access the HDD and memory modules and cmos battery. Remove 2 screws holding the HDD to the case, pull the drive to the left and remove from motherboard.

Simple search of your model number there were many links that was the first one I looked at for your model, loosen probably means they are captured so they won’t get lost.

I see you also added photos of stripped out screw heads you still may be able to get them loose with the proper sized driver. But make sure that you are turning the screw not stripping it you may have to file a slot if they are stripped out two far or get a stripped screw extractor kit I have one I got from Sears years ago it works great in a small electric impact driver or electric drill in reverse.

Comment: ok @ed-beal I loosened it (it's been loosened since this morning). I need to see if I can jimmy it open.

Comment: loosened was the key term. i jimmied the cover open.

Answer (score 1):

The post on the inside that the screw screws into is probably broken.  Just ignore it and move on to the next one.

Comment: Both screws have same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for your laptop's model number on [IFIXIT](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Dell_Laptop). You will find helpful diagrams and photos, including the list of exact tools required for the repair.  I hope this helps.